# square-connect 4.2.3 Your app should work on its own without requiring installation of another app to function

Tags: xcode, square-connect

I have been reading the Apple app store guidelines. And I came across this:

4.2.3 Your app should work on its own without requiring installation of another app to function.

Given this how do I get my app through the App store review process when it requires the installation of the Square POS app in order to function?

Comment: Does your application do anything other than point of sale, such as adding things to carts, specialized calculations, or other additional functionality? Plenty of other apps on are on the app store that use our APIs.

Comment: Yes. My app does some of the things you mentioned. But I thought the Apple paragraph was quite clear. I don't see how it could be interpreted any other way. If it doesn't mean what it says then perhaps Apple should change it.